# How to request an Asp.Net page manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a project and it contains 2 pages: `test1.aspx` and `test2.aspx`. Now from test1.aspx I want to manually request `test2.aspx` and get the HTML out of it. I could do this using `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. Problem is I have a firewall and I suspect it won't work. Is there any other way to download the content from the webpage without actually using `HttpWebRequest`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried what you suspect won't work? You might find that it does, after all.

Comment: @Adrian: Can I specify relative paths in HttpWebRequest. I guess not. If I can't specify relative paths I am sure firewall would cause an issue.

Comment: why do you want to 'get' the HTML? perhaps there's an alternate way to do what you need... although if they are on the same server like you said, firewall would be a non issue because the request will never touch the internet

Comment: @Jack No, but you can look up the path that you're running in and put that before test2.aspx. I do recommend trying it, as it's the easiest solution.

Comment: My advice would be to refactor the content of test2.aspx into a control that you can then use in test1.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like what you are trying to do ;) Anyway, since your page don't seems to be a static page (.aspx) you must do a request to your webserver, whatever the method you use (`HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest`).

Usually, a request done on the same machine does not passes through the network. If the DNS alias point to the machine IP address a loopback occurs.

In this case:

- if your firewall is somewhere on your network, you don't care about
  it, the request will not leave your host
- if you speak about a firewall software, on your machine, it may block
  the request. You may have to authorize such requests or force the DNS locally in your host file to specify `127.0.0.1` (which is a true localhost) and may work with
  most firewall software
- if you are on a Windows Server and your site require authentication, you may have to deal with [Loopback
  Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd582692.aspx) (or [here](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/07/a-quick-guide-to-configuring-the-loopback-check/))

NB: Loopbacks are usually considered as security breach and not recommended.

You should think about another solution like Ajax Web Services, Web or User controls (as already said) etc...